# Why is the function not printing the sum of the values in the list?

Tags: python, list, function, variables

The goal of this program is for the function 'Fib' to take in two values, and put them through a Fibonacci sequence, adding terms to the variable 'sequence' as it goes along. When it goes through the 'check' function and returns Limit Reached, it will add even values to the list 'final', then after looping print out the sum of 'final'.

The problem is that no matter what values Fib takes in, 'final' always ends up with no values. I'm very new to programming and can't seem to figure out why it's doing this...

```
def even(x):
    v = list(str(x))[-1]
    if v == '0' or v == '2' or v == '4' or v == '6' or v == '8':
        return x
    else:
        return 0 
def check(sequence):
    for v in sequence:
        if v >= 20:
            return 'Limit Reached'
        else:
            return None

def Fib(x,y):
    sequence = [x,y]
    a = 0
    b = 1
    final = []
    while len(sequence) < 100:
        term = sequence[a] + sequence[b]
        sequence.append(term)
        if check(sequence) == 'Limit Reached':
            for v in sequence:
                final.apppend(even(v))
            print sum(final)
            break
        a += 1
        b += 1
```

Comment: you might want to do some new code:

for v in sequence:
  if v % 2 == 0:
    final.append(v)

Comment: As I understand Fib() function operates on integers so better way is just do bit operation: `somevalue & 1` what is equal 1 only if number is odd (not even)

Comment: @ddzialak:  It's probably preferable to use `%` for number parity testing, as that operator lies in the semantic domain of integers, rather than their representation.  We might be able to prove that `a % 2 == a & 1`, but unless we originally set out to do something bitwise, I think it's better to use `%`.  There may be certain cases where there could be reasons not to follow this, but this is obviously a question relevant to beginners, not fancy bit-twiddling hacks.

Answer (score 4):

`check` will always return `None` if the first item in the list is less than 20.

You probably meant:

```
def check(sequence):
    for v in sequence:
        if v >= 20:
            return 'Limit Reached'
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: @ecatmur I think I like this use of `else` after the `for` loop and I will use it from now on.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues with this code.  I would have written it like this:

```
def even(x):
    # is the modulo operator, it's used to calculate a remainder
    return x % 2 == 0

def check(sequence):
    # you need to check all the values, not just the first one
    return max(sequence) >= 20

def Fib(x, y):
    sequence = [x, y]

    while len(sequence) < 100:
        # it's not necessary to keep a and b around, you can use 
        # negative indices instead
        sequence.append(sequence[-2] + sequence[-1])

        if check(sequence):
            # this is called a "generator comprehension"
            print sum(v for v in sequence if even(v))
            break
```

It's still possible to simplify further, but this structure matches your own.  It's actually not necessary to even keep `sequence` around, as you can keep a running total as you go, but I figured it would be more instructive to see it done this way.

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning final, so its value is cleared each time you call Fib(), because it's a local variable. I'm sure it prints out the expected result, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Python, differently from most languages, will throw a runtime error on a typo like this (as opposed to not compiling your program at all).

```
 final.apppend(even(v))
```

Not seeing the runtime error demonstrates that the surrounding `if` condition is never satisfied, and that is because the `check` method returns immediately after the first item in the sequence is checked, as opposed to checking the whole sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something much simpler:

```
def fib(a, b, iterations = 20):
    result = 0
    if not (a & 1): result += a
    if not (b & 1): result += b
    for x in xrange(iterations):
        nextval = a + b
        if not (nextval & 1):
            result += nextval
        a = b
        b = nextval
    return result
```